# searching string containing 6 words for real words

Tags: python

I am importing a "dictionary" file containing words that I read in as an array. I then want to search a 6 word phrase being generated by a permutation function for each one of those words and print out if a match is found from the dictionary array to any of the words in the phrase. If I could print out only if it finds matches for the whole phrase that would be preferable. The output of the permutation results in a string of 6 words separated by spaces.

Thanks

```
import itertools
import array
arr=[]
f = file('/home/kyle/dictionary.csv').readlines()
for i in range(len(f)):
    arr.append(f[i].rstrip('\n').rstrip('\r').split(','))

for a in range(0, len(arr)):
    print arr[a]

s=['e','k','y','a','v','y','a','a','o','s','r','h','t','n','i','k','h','t','s','t','e','n','i','p','p','l','e','h','d','c','t','e','f','a','t','t','l']
for L in range(1, len(s)+1):
for subset in itertools.permutations(s, 37):
    x=( "".join(subset))
    s=x[:5] + ' ' + x[5:]
    s=s[:16] + ' ' + s[16:]
    s=s[:20] + ' ' + s[20:]
    s=s[:27] + ' ' + s[27:]
    s=s[:31] + ' ' + s[31:]
    s=s[:35] + ' ' + s[35:]
    for c in range(0,len(arr)):

        test=str(arr[c])
        if test in s:
            print s
```

The bottom part was playing with "in" to find possible matches but that didn't seem to turn out any results. The code is pretty messy

Comment: what have you done so far? show us some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps, this is a very naive implementation, but might be useful as a start point.

```
In [2]: words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5', 'word6', 'word7']

In [3]: phrase1 = 'bla bla word1 bla word2 bla word7'

In [4]: phrase2 = 'bla bla word1 bla word2 bla word7 word6, word4 word3'

In [5]: def match(phrase):
   ...:     n_matches = 0
   ...:     for w in words:
   ...:         if w in phrase:
   ...:             n_matches += 1
   ...:     return n_matches == 6
   ...: 

In [6]: match(phrase1)
Out[6]: False

In [7]: match(phrase2)
Out[7]: True
```

The problem is that we find substrings:

```
In [8]: phrase3 = 'bla bla word1 bla word2 bla word7 word6, word4 word3failed'

In [9]: match(phrase3)
Out[9]: True
```

And I fixed this way:

```
In [22]: import re
In [25]: tokenize_words = re.compile(r'\w+')
In [30]: def match(phrase):
   ....:     n_matches = 0
   ....:     phrase_words = tokenize_words.findall(phrase)
   ....:     for w in words:
   ....:         if w in phrase_words:
   ....:             n_matches += 1
   ....:     return n_matches == 6
   ....: 

In [31]: match(phrase2)
Out[31]: True

In [32]: match(phrase3)
Out[32]: False

In [33]: match(phrase1)
Out[33]: False
```

Comment: This appears to be running, it has been going at it since 2:45ET last night. No solutions yet. Before your fix it was finding 8+ matches and now I'm guessing that there will only be a few that are possible.

Comment: Amazingly it is still running. I don't think there is going to be a real answer to this word/sentence scramble. The common consensus is that one letter is wrong but I guess I will find out when it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is correct but the problem is that there are N! (N!=N* (N-1)* (N-2)*..*2*1) permutations of N elements.

In your case you are permuting 37 elements:

```
37!=13763753091226345046315979581580902400000000
```

so your code is going to take quite a long time to find useful answers.

What might work better is to try to construct valid phrases by keeping track of how many of each type of letter you have available.

The idea would be to construct a recursive function that attempts to produce all k-word phrases given counts of how many of each letter type you have available:

1) Loop over each word in your dictionary in turn

2) If you don't have enough letters left to make the word then skip to the next word and go back to step 1

3) If you do have enough letters, make a new collection containing the remaining letters.

4) If k=1 then you have reached the bottom of the recursion and can print the result

5) Otherwise you can recursively call the function to make a k-1 word phrase from the collection of the remaining letters.

Comment: This was the big issue when I set off is that it would take so much time. While there is about 10^43 permutations of this 37 character string, each permutation is being compared to ~173K words in a dictionary array. This will take time.